# How to apply jacoco filter

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, lombok, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a working jacoco maven plugin and want to exclude 
code generated by lombok.
I found option LOMBOK.DATA, though I don't know what to do with it.

Putting it into exclude doesn't affect anything.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
  <configuration>
    <exclude>                                
      <exclude>LOMBOK.DATA</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-agent</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>report</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You don't close excludes tag properly.

Comment: Besides some XML incorrectness in the example above, this feature has not yet been implemented in Jacoco, it has only been proposed. See: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15